# How To Make A Cutout In A Gear

Tags: objects, vertices, workflow

I have made a gear in blender, but now I need to make a cutout for a pin in it. What’s the best way to do this?

[image: this is how it must look like]
[image: this is what i have]

Comment: Try the boolean modifier

Comment: Try *BoolTool* add on also.

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a plane and scale and adjust to make a rectangular shape.
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to apply scale and rotation
3. Select the vertex and Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> with the scroll wheel round the edges
4. Press <kbd>E</kbd> to Extrude
5. Press <kbd>N</kbd> to flip normal
6. Select the gear add Boolean Modifier
7. Target the plane and the operation as difference. Apply and delete the plane.

See gif below:

---

[image]

Comment: <kbd> tags around keyboard keys please.

Comment: @ocasoprotal While it's nice to do the formatting for other people, they also have to learn to do it themselves.

Comment: @RayMairlot Sorry, that's not how [so] or bse works. Or at least how **I** use to work on these sites. Everyone is able to do edits, so why wait for the edit? If you see that you can improve a post, just do it ;)

Comment: @OcasoProtal Hope you can see by my [edits](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/241/ray-mairlot?tab=activity&sort=revisions) that I know how the site works, but when a regular user is reminded of certain formatting ideals and doesn't do them it doesn't necessarily do much good to continually do it for them (as I have in the past) as opposed to trying to get them into the habit of doing it themselves.

Comment: I'm using Blender 2.9 and I cannot find the command described by atek.
Although I finally found out that a "quick" solution to apply boolean over a gear can be to export the gear as .stl and to import it back.
The imported gear is then easier to work with.